# Xcode 3.2.5 fail to produce an IPA

Tags: xcode, adhoc, ipa

i think i'm missing something very trivial here.

i made an ad-hoc provisioning profile, hit "Build And Archive", opened the organizer, and hit "Share" and i get ( creating signed IPA archive ) but when i click ( show in finder ) i only find the ".apparchive" folder. No IPA file whatsoever.

i created an app in the iTunes Connect portal and i used the ( Submit ) and ( Validate ) options, still nothing, can't find the IPA archive it says it's creating

Comment: Mm, I wish compiling my code would brew and serve *me* an IPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to package your IPA file through command line, so you can have full log in it. Here is a post I wrote, check it out. http://www.nanaimostudio.com/blog/2011/4/17/xcode-build-and-archive-sharing-problem-and-solution.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sharing it with yourself via e-mail?

Comment: same thing, ( creating signed IPA archive ) and then nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before if I was either missing the Distribution certificate, or had a duplicate for some reason.  Check Keychain Access to be sure you have a *single* valid distribution profile for the developer cert that the ad hoc profile is signed against (which you can verify in the profile portal)